# What does 辞書形＋ ぞって mean?

Tags: grammar

> たくさん食べるぞって日はお休みの前日とかにしてます

I saw it in a YouTube video. I tried looking it up in the dictionary but I found こぞって only. I'm not sure if this is it or is that a different grammar rule?

Comment: Would you understand it if it were 「たくさん食べるぞ」って日?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment above, this is a case of omitted comma, or, てん and/or かぎかっこ「」。

「たくさん、食べるぞ！」、って【いう】日は、お休みの前日とかにしてます。

Well ya know, sometimes you wanna eat till you burst. But I make a point to not do that before a workday.